# Short story about a man remembering simple pleasures of the past in a bleak future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

The story is likely by Robert Sheckley, and one of his shorter ones.

If memory serves, it ends with a man visiting another man in a cave and exchanging something for a shoebox of junk items. I believe he was buying time to hold the items, not actually purchasing them. These items remind the man of things as they once were in a bleak world where all is lost after some form of world-ending event.

Similar themes to "[Store of the Worlds](https://sfshortstories.com/?p=6448)" by Sheckley, but not that story.

Comment: Was this story set in a post-apocalyptic future?

Comment: yes it was, after some form of world-ending event.

Comment: And the questioner is *sure* that it is not Store of the Worlds ? (he asked plaintively)
It would seem to be such a good fit.

Comment: I thought about that myself. Read the end of Store of the Worlds. The exchange is in the wrong direction (in SotW, the guy who travels gives the parcel to the other guy, which is the opposite of what I remember, and I could swear it was in a shoebox). I was pretty sure getting to hold these pieces of junk was a big deal to the recipient, not just an exchange of the items being sufficient payment. It's possible I am crossing two stories or remembering SotW wrong. Not sure.